# Как писать на C в Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Как установить язык `C` в Visual Studio 2017?
Нужен именно `C`, а не `C++` или `C#`. При установке просто нет обычного `C`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ставьте С++ и работайте на C без проблем. Отдельно не поставите, они слишком взаимосвязаны :)

Comment: Практически во всех современных компиляторах С и С++ "ставятся" вместе и одновременно и реализуются одним и тем же компилятором. Ничего специального выбирать не надо: ставьте С++ в Visual Studio, а вместе с ним поставится и С.

Answer (score 3):

Компиляцией С и С++ в студии занимается один и тот же компилятор. Файлы с расширением .c автоматически компилируются как С код. Также это можно задать вручную посредством [параметра `/TC`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется писать на чистом си, при этом не особо хочется устанавливать большие пакеты студии, можно воспользоваться компилятором+IDE [Pelles C](http://www.pellesc.de/index.php?page=overview&lang=en) - маленький, легенький, поддерживает с99, можно писать консольные и оконные приложения.